# I want to use a System.AccessToken to a rest api call to deploy one release

Tags: azure-devops, deployment

In Azure Pipeline Releases, I have one task "Azure PowerShell".
[image: 207908-image.png]

This script will do a deployment of another release. In my code, I use a System.AutenticantionToken: "$AzureDevOpsToken = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" and my headers for a call rest API is:

```
$basicAuthValue = "Bearer $AzureDevOpsToken"
$headers = @{
Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}
```

When I ran this code :

```
    $deploymentBody = @{
    status = "inProgress"
    } | ConvertTo-Json
    $urlDeployment = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$Organization/$ProjectName/_apis/Release/releases/$ReleaseId/environments/$EnvironmentId`?api-version=5.1-preview.6"
    $deployment = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $urlDeployment -Method Patch -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header -UseBasicParsing -Body $deploymentBody
```

I received an error:
2022-06-01T14:53:15.4901741Z {"$id":"1","customProperties":{"Descriptor":null,"IdentityDisplayName":null,"Token":null,"RequestedPermissions":0,"NamespaceId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},"innerException":null,"message":"VS402904: Access denied: User e3b793c5-a512-44b7-a704-878e8adb62e9 does not have manage deployments permission. Contact your release manager.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Security.AccessCheckException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"AccessCheckException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

This happened when I use a System.AccessToken.

But when I use a Personal Access Token it goes well. But I don't want to use it because I need to put the password in plain sight in the pipeline. So I want to use a System.AccessToken.

In my pipeline, on the agent pool, I have this check: "Allow scripts to access the OAuth token"

Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

> VS402904: Access denied: User e3b793c5-a512-44b7-a704-878e8adb62e9 does not have manage deployments permission.

Based on the error message, it means that the service account has no access to manage the deployment.

The variable: $(system.accesstoken) will create a token based on the permissions of the service account: **{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})**.

Refer to this doc: [Scoped build identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scoped-build-identities)

To solve this issue, you need to navigate to **Piplines -> Release -> Security** and grant the **Manage Deployments** permission to the service account: **{Project Name} Build Service ({Org Name})**.

For example:

[image]

Comment: I already do that but the problem continues.

Comment: @Filipa can you edit your question to share the permission setting screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use the password plaintext for the personal access token. You can set a variable lets call it `PAT` on your pipeline with the `value` as a secret and then inject this variable on your powershell script.

[image]

```
 $connectionToken="$(PAT)"
 $base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
```

Then you have to use as a header

```
-Headers @{authorization = "Basic $base64AuthInfo"}
```

Comment: Yes, but PATs expire. -- I don't want to have to update the build every six months when nothing has changed, just to generate a new PAT. -- Using a random user's PAT in a build pipeline is just bad practice anyway.